# Using the Chooser with specific file extensions in ios

Tags: ios, dropbox, dropbox-api

Said **We expect to add this feature to the Android and iOS Choosers in the future** in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/50/using-the-chooser-with-specific-file-extensions), August 14, 2013. But until now, January 20, 2015, I still can't find this feature for iOS in any document or tutorial. Does iOS have this feature and how to use it (if have)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Chooser on Android and iOS doesn't support filtering by file extension.

Comment: Is there anyway to handle this on iOS?

Comment: I'm not sure what more information you're looking for. The Chooser on iOS doesn't support this.